# android: how to draw a simple line and display it in a widget?

Tags: java, android, graphics, bitmap, drawable

i want to visualize stuff with a widget by drawing some lines. lets just say i get two coordinates (x,y) every n seconds and then want to update the widget accordingly. this works just fine by now, but now i want to actually DRAW a line between those two points.

i googled around and found many things, but nothing explaining the fundamentals of drawing on an image. since i have NO experience with graphics, i imagine these things to work somehow like graphics drawn with tikzpicture in LaTeX.

can someone please explain to me the how this all works - or at least point me to an example explaining this from the start? it would be highly appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: At most, without human interaction, your widget will update every 30 minutes. Therefore, animation should not be possible. Therefore, you'll be better off just inserting your image.

Comment: well - i'm triggering the update of the widget via appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews); - works just fine

Comment: so, you created a timer thread in your appWidgetManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html

may help for a start. unfortunately, this still leaves me clueless how to actually DRAW on a widgets layout...

... and to answer this by myself: [android: how to add a customized image to widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359267/android-how-to-add-a-customized-image-to-widgets)

Answer (score 4):

In the Android is usually all comes down to drawing on the canvas, e.g. as in the method View.onDraw().

```
// prepare picture
if (mBackground != null) {
    mBackground.recycle();
}
mBackground = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas backgroundCanvas = new Canvas(mBackground);
backgroundCanvas.scale(width, height);
RectF rect = new RectF(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#18a518")); // gray

// draw line
backgroundCanvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);
```

onDraw():

```
// draw picture on View canvas
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, 0, 0, null);
}
```

**ADD**

A primitive chain is as follows: 
1 create your own View class (extend). 
2 Define `onDraw()` method in your View. 
3 Place your View in layout xml file (or add in runtime: `Activity.addContentView()`).
4 If needed redraw, call `invalidate(); // forces onDraw() to be called`.
For detailed information see android examples by google.

Then, if you want improve efficiency, learn SurfaceView. But in surface we drawing on canvas too.

Comment: thanks! few further questions: 1.) how does this work in details? do i "create" an image which is then used by the layout? 2.) do i need some kind of context for the code above to work?

Comment: unfortunately, i don't really get this... I think I need to start from a far more basic point: what is a "canvas"? whats the difference to "paint"? i think i understand the concept of a "view". but i especially dont understand how those things are interconnected! unfortunately, google (as is developer.android) isnt helping at all, as they explain this all way too high-level for me :( my "vision" is, that i somehow "create" a picture (a canvas, i guess?) and pass it to a view-object, which again causes the contents of the canvas to be drawn on the view... !?