# How can i draw a line on my own layout?

Tags: android, layout

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    private static final String TAG = "DrawView";

    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);.......
```

**Guys i have to classes this class is for drawing line there is a long code and this is working but it is working on black, blue or any other solid color i want it to be drawn in my lay out **

```
public class matchFun extends Activity {
DrawView drawView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
      //  setContentView(R.layout.matchfun);
      //  setContentView(drawView);
       drawView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.matchfun);
        drawView.requestFocus();....
```

**This is the class which is inheriting the upper one i want to draw line in second class  **

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back_lightblue"
    >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="4dp"
    android:layout_y="118dp" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:onClick="buttonClickHandler"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="7dp"
    android:layout_y="196dp" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:onClick="buttonClickHandler"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

**This my xml  Please suggest me any idea please resolve this problem im working on it from last couple of weeks and still couldnt find any solution**

Comment: We discussed similar question one day ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296712/android-how-to-draw-a-simple-line-and-display-it-in-a-widget. Are you know about search?

Answer (score 0):

To Draw a line on any layout you have to use the Canvas.  And if you want to draw on your image just make the canvas view transparent.  When you are using it, it seems like you are working on it.

I think it will work.  If you want to know more about it, see
[Android Draw canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) .